# Why is this a valid function declaration in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
Foo x(Bar());
```

I can write in inside another function and it compiles. Why?
Also how a function declaration can get a temporary object in it's signature?

Comment: it's not temp. object. it's function that gets nothing and returns Bar

Comment: @Peter you sure? https://ideone.com/Vgg6Ia

Comment: @Peter You are wrong.

Comment: @Peter, not in this context

Comment: A typical workaround is using uniform initialization: `Foo x{Bar{}};`. Some people don't like it because they prefer `vector<int> v(1, 2);` with the content of `{2}` over `vector<int> v{1, 2};` with the content `{1, 2}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can do this:

```
Foo x();
```

This declares a function `x` that takes no arguments and returns `Foo`.

We can add parameters:

```
Foo x(int y, char z);
```

A parameter is just a variable declaration (`x` and `z` here).

We can omit the parameter names in a function declaration:

```
Foo x(int, char);
```

And we can declare a parameter as a function:

```
Foo x(Bar y());
```

Here we declare `x` as a function taking another function `y` (that takes no arguments and returns `Bar`) returning `Foo`.

Finally we can omit the parameter name here, too:

```
Foo x(Bar ());  // a function taking a function
```

That's how the syntax works.

Semantically, you might object, this is invalid because functions aren't value types. You can't copy a function, so you can't pass it by value. Which is true, but there's a rule that says any parameter declared as a function is silently adjusted to be a pointer by the compiler:

```
Foo x(Bar y());
// really means:
Foo x(Bar (*y)());
```

`x` takes a *pointer to* a function (taking no arguments and returning `Bar`).

Or without parameter names:

```
Foo x(Bar ());
// same as:
Foo x(Bar (*)());
```

This is similar to the rule that turns a parameter declared as an array into a pointer:

```
Foo x(Bar [42]);
// same as:
Foo x(Bar *);
```

Comment: Why can I declare in inside another function and not only in the global scope? but when I want to add a body to the function I get an error